# Await until functions are fired inside

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux

I have the next functions:

```
export const getSet = async (
    projectId,
    setId,
    dispatch
) => await (
    projectId && setId &&
    setsDb
    .child(`${projectId}/${setId}`)
    .once("value", async snap => {
        const set = snap.val();

        const elements = Object.keys(set);
        const elementsClasses = await getClassesForElements(projectId, elements);

        const classes = Object.values(elementsClasses);
        const classesAttributes = await getClassesAttributes(projectId, classes);

        dispatch(setClasses(classesAttributes));
        dispatch(setElements(elementsClasses));
        dispatch(setSet(set));
    })
);

export const getPageDetails = (projectId, pageId) => (
    dispatch => (
        projectId && pageId &&
        pagesDb
        .child(`${projectId}/${pageId}`)
        .once("value", async snap => {
            const pageDetails = snap.val();
            const { setId } = pageDetails;

            await getSet(projectId, setId, dispatch)

            dispatch(
                setPageDetails(
                    pageDetails
                )
            );
        })
    )
);
```

I don't have too much experience in async functions, but what I want to earn is to make `getPageDetails` wait with `dispatch(setPageDetails(pageDetails))` until `getSet` finishes all the dispatches. In the above functions everything works fine except that `getSet` finishes latest. How to solve this?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is only going to pause things if the expression you are waiting for evaluates to a promise.

`once` takes a callback, so presumably, it doesn't return a promise.

Therefore you need to [wrap it with a function which does return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) that resolves when `once` is done (which means converting all the `dispatch` calls too).